Azure Policy does not restrict SQL capacity changes correctly
I have a custom Azure policy to restrict SQL databases to specific capacities. The environment is made up entirely of Basic & Standard tier databases - there's another (working!) policy in place to ensure this.
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
          "field": "type"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.capacity",
          "notIn": ["5", "10"]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}

However the policy blocks any scale or creation operation, regardless of if the capacity is correct or not.
Tried replacing the array with a parameter, and tried passing in the capacities as strings or integers - none make a difference, the policy always blocks the action. Targeted resources do show up in the policy compliance UI, but always non-compliant.


Azure Policy does not restrict SQL capacity changes correctly

I also tested your policy with the same field, but it is blocking all capacities instead of 5 and 10.
Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.capacity

Alternatively, you can use the below policy to restrict the SQL database if the capacity numbers 5 and 10 are not specified.
Here is the cmd to check the list of capacity's in specific region.
az sql db list-editions -l eastus -o table

As per your requirement, you want to allow only capacities 5 and 10. Below are the SKUs that have capacity numbers 5 and 10.
Free,Basic,S0,GP_Gen5_10,GP_S_Gen5_10,BC_Gen5_10,BC_DC_10,HS_DC_10,HS_MOPRMS_10,HS_PRMS_10,HS_Gen5_10


Azure Policy:
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.name",
            "in": "[parameters('allowedSkus')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "allowedSkus": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed SKUs",
        "description": "The list of allowed SKUs for SQL databases."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Free",
        "Basic",
        "S0",
        "GP_Gen5_10",
        "GP_S_Gen5_10",
        "BC_Gen5_10",
        "BC_DC_10",
        "HS_DC_10",
        "HS_MOPRMS_10",
        "HS_PRMS_10",
        "HS_Gen5_10"
      ]
    }
  }
}

The policy blocks the SQL Database creation if I select any capacity other than 5 and 10

The policy accepts resource creation if I select capacity numbers 5 and 10.


Unfortunately this seems to have broken - sku.name now seems to resolve to Standard, Basic etc instead of the actual SKU name it did before. sku.capacity and other related fields are still blocking all changes, regardless of whether it should or not.
